# Real-World Origin of Avrupa(n) and Hijer(o) in Patricia C. Wrede's 'Frontier Magic' Series?

Tags: frontier-magic

In this alternate history/reality fantasy series, set in a Frontier North America with magic, there are 3 main magical theory systems mentioned - *Aphrikan*, *Avrupan* and *Hijero-Cathayan*.

Aphrican magic is clearly (both etymologically and in-verse) 'African' magic. And *Cathay* is equally easily identified with China. *Avrupa* is the in-universe name for Europe. But what is the **Hijero** referring to and where does the alternate name of **Avrupa** for 'Europe' come from?

<sub>Note: I've read some speculation that *Hijero* might be Indian, but even leaving real world comparison to tradition systems and the fact that I can't find any similar alternate name for any region of India, Indian magic is referred to as a separate entity by the Hijero-Cathayan adept in Book 3. So that doesn't seem to be it. As for *Avrupa*, the closest real-life etymology I've been able to find is that it's a Sanskrit word meaning *deformed/misshapen*. Which might be acceptable as a name for a tradition of magic, but doesn't really make sense as the self-identified name by the people of a continent.</sub>

Comment: It's just speculation on my part (since I don't know the series) but the (doric) Greek word for Europe (the mythological gal, the continent is named after) is "Εὐρώπα", pronounced Eurṓpā. If you additionally substitute the "Av" of "Arvrupa" with an "Eu" you are there.

Comment: It might be a stretch, but could *Hijero-* come from *Hyderabad*? From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyderabad_State): "At the time of the partition of India, the State of Hyderabad was the largest and most prosperous of all princely states in India."

Comment: @PeterShor: Idk, seems unlikely. As I mention in my OP, in the books a practicioner of the Hijero-Cathayan style refers to an item/'spell' of Indian magic as something distinct from his own Hijero-Cathayan magic. In addition to that - the pronunciation of Hyderabad nothing even close to Hijero and both culturally and geographically they are pretty apart. ... [cont...

Comment: ... cont]... The book does tend to conflate cultures (entirety of giantly diverse continent of Africa is one-blob of samey identity) but even then, it seems weird that a heavily Persian influenced South/Central Indian culture would be conflated with a Chinese tradition...

Comment: As for 'Hijero': In Spanish the 'j' is pronounced like the 'ch' in 'van Goch' or 'Loch'. The Spanish word for "Wizard" is 'hechicero'. Spanish would (in my opinion) indicate South America - you know: Inca & Maya magic...

Comment: @Einer: in Patricia Wrede's world in these books, there were no pre-European inhabitants of North or South American (anybody with insufficient firepower who tried to settle was eaten by magical monsters), so the Inca and Mayans never existed.

Answer (score 4):

As is discussed in the other answer, *Avrupa* is derived from *Europe*. The Latin spelling of *Europe* was *Evropa*, which is not far from *Avrupa*.

Hijero-Cathayan may imply Japanese-Chinese. A *hijiri* is a Japanese holy man. From the [encyclopedia of religion](https://www.encyclopedia.com/article-1G2-3424501344/hijiri.html):

> HIJIRI are Japanese lay ascetics and influential antagonists of priests and monks. The role of the hijiri in Japanese folk religion is far more important than that of the ministers of the official religions (priests and monks in Shintō and Buddhism, respectively). The hijiri is in many ways the spokesman of the common man.

And from [the Edopedia](https://edoflourishing.blogspot.com/2013/02/hijiri-holy-men.html):

> Hijiri: in Japanese religion, a man of great personal magnetism and spiritual power, as distinct from a leader of an institutionalized religion. 
>   Historically, hijiri has been used to refer to sages of various traditions, such as the shaman, Shintō mountain ascetic, Taoist magician, or Buddhist reciter. 
>   Most characteristically hijiri describes the wandering priest who operates outside the orthodox Buddhist tradition to meet the religious needs of the common people.

So *hijiri* are already, in the real world, connected with magicians. One can imagine uniting traditional Chinese magic with the magic practiced by Japanese wandering holy magicians to obtain a unified theory of Japanese-Chinese magic.

Answer (score 3):

- **Avrupa** literally means 'Europe' in Turkish ([source](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/english-turkish/europe))
- **Hijero** seems to be a contortion of 'hiero' (as in **hiero**-glyphics), possibly from the Serbo-Croat but more likely also from the [Turkish](https://translate.google.com/#en/tr/hieroglyph) (["hijeroglifski"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hijeroglifski))

In the 'Frontier Magic' universe, it seems likely that 'Europe' is called Avrupa due to a much stronger influence over European affairs by the erstwhile Turkish Empire whereas the fact that Hijero (Egypt) and Cathay (China) are conflated might suggest a Egyptian/Chinese Empire.

Comment: This is really great info about the origin of the words. I don't think Hijero-Cathay suggests a Egyptian-Chinese Empire (because frankly, that's just too different and far apart to be at all plausible) but it seems to be a possible explanation that ancient Egyptian magics that were used to build the Pyramids have been in 'current' time been conflated with Cathayan magic as being so similar as to be labelled the same school of magic, specially when compared with Avrupan and Aphrikan styles.

Comment: I'd be happy to accept this answer, if the reference to an Egyptian/Chinese Empire is removed (since I don't feel that's supported by anything) and everything else in the answer seems totally on point.

Comment: @Shisa - The connection is that both words mean something in the same language; Turkish. The other answers are excellent, but there's no obvious linkage.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand how both words meaning something in Turkish supports the existence of an Egyptian-Chinese Empire. That is my only reservation with this answer. Could you explain?

Comment: @Shisa - It's the only place that both words exist together. The other examples come from *multiple* languages.

Comment: I am not at all comparing your answer with other answers, merely asking for more detail on how the existence of both words in Turkish "strongly suggests" a joint Egypto-Chinese "Empire" (given the vast physical distances and cultural differences and the *7000 km* between the two locations) I'd be happy to take this to chat if you'd want to elaborate.

Comment: @Shisa - I'm happy to agree that it's a tenuous link. I don't know enough about the canon universe to argue that it's anything other than a possibility.

Comment: In an era before exploration and mass communication, don't overestimate the accuracy of geographical names. I don't think this is the explanation, but either "Egypt" "or "China" becoming the generic term for "Eastern" or "Oriental" is perfectly plausible, so that the compound "Hijero-Cathayan" simply means "exotic oriental Egyptian" or "exotic oriental Chinese" -- or even "simply "Oriental".